# PayPal Subscription Payment Issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I currently am encountering the following response from PayPal when attempting to process a Subscription payment.

2 times out of 10, this is what we are experiencing when we try to execute a billing agreement:

```
err: Error: Response Status : 400
httpStatusCode: 400
message: "Response Status : 400"
response: Object
debug_id: "bdbdb346c2726"
httpStatusCode: 400
information_link: "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_TOKEN"
message: "The token is invalid"
name: "INVALID_TOKEN"
__ proto__: Object
stack: undefined
__ proto__: Error
result: null
this: global
```

Any help in troubleshooting the issue would be greatly appreciated. Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to Paypal support.

Answer (score 0):

Based on PayPal's log, the error message is EXECUTE_AGREEMENT_BUYER_NOT_ACCEPTED, It looks like buyer didn't accept this agreement, so you can't create billing agreement based on the token.

Comment: If the question can only be answered by reference to Paypal logs it is proof that it's off-topic.